# Multiple images in one

Tags: css

I ask myself how use multiple images in one. For example youtube -> http://s.ytimg.com/yt/img/master-vfl102488.png 
sorry for my english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are referring to are [CSS sprites](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/).

Answer (score 1):

[Another example](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/) on A List Apart. Everyone who works with HTML in some shape or form should read it.